# Cross Compiling Perl or Expect for MIPS Processor

Tags: perl, cross-platform, mips, expect, codesourcery

I am working with an embedded board that has a MIPS processsor.  I am supposed to be developing tests for the system with different applications. My question is: is there a way to cross-compile Perl or Expect for the target board. My understanding is that the board we use is MIPS with a 800 MHz processor. Not sure of the model number. I know that we use CodeSourcery to compile all applications.

Is there a way to use CodeSourcery or other tools to compile Perl or Expect for the target board?

Comment: If the proposal for [Improving Cross compilation of Perl 5](http://news.perlfoundation.org/2012/05/grant-application-improving-cr.html) by [castaway](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4840/castaway) is granted and completed, cross-compiling will be much easier for everyone. Community, please share this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Cross-compiling Perl for ARM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464538/cross-compile-perl-for-arm), and do the same thing, but with correct (i.e. MIPS) values for targetarch and the Code Sourcery MIPS compiler.